# How to use palettegen and paletteuse filters with FFmpeg for image sequences?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, jpeg, sequence, animated-gif

I have converted a short video to gif with the help of the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

palette="/tmp/palette.png"

filters="fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos"

ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

However when I convert an image sequence, I get error message: "Filter paletteuse has a unconnected output"

```
#!/bin/sh

palette="/tmp/palette.png"

filters="fps=25"

ffmpeg -v warning -f image2 -i %04d.jpg -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -v warning -f image2 -i %04d.jpg -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

How can I make palettegen and paletteuse work with the image sequences too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[palettegen](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen) and [paletteuse](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) work fine with image sequence inputs.

The problem is with your [positional parameter](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html). You're using `$2`, but there is only one argument passed from your command to your script. Change the `$2` to `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need right syntax:

```
# ./videogif.sh bf5_orig.webm battlefield5.gif
```

$2 = output filename (.gif)